Why aren't more flight schools covered by the Pell Grant and student loans?
I tried to find flight schools in Alabama that accept the Pell Grant. There are none. The are large collages that do take student loans and Pell but require you to live on campus. So, why are there not more smaller fight schools not set up so I don't have to travel 6 hours away?

A quick trawl through easily accessible documentation online suggests that the Pell Grants are administered through the educational system, up to community colleges and universities. Flight schools are generally commercial training companies, not educational institutions and therefor might not be eligible to participate. I can't be definitive about this, hence not an answer. You might get an answer by reframing the question along the lines of "How is school eligibility for Pell Grants determined?" and posting the question on [academia.se]

It's likely that there's a fair amount of overhead required in order to qualify to receive federal student loans, which smaller organizations probably don't want to deal with. It's also possible that they already have all the business they can handle, so they have no need to attract more by accepting loans.
